# matar un job en dataproc desde airflow

Tags: composer, google-cloud-platform

Estoy trabajando con google dataproc, google composer y apache airflow, pero tengo el problema que cuando
se ejecuta mi flujo con un schedule desde airflow en ocasiones X job en lugar de durar 3 minutos, por dar un ejemplo, sobrepasa ese tiempo y nunca termina (la última vez duró 1 hora ), por lo tanto tengo que manualmente detener el job, existe alguna forma de que en cierto tiempo(digamos 10 minutos) mate el job haya terminado o no?

ya utilice **execution_timeout**, en el dag si le hace caso y lo pinta de amarillo(upstream_failed) al sobrepasar el tiempo que le defino, pero en dataproc no detiene como tal el job y continúa con la ejecución.

también utilicé **init_action_timeout** pero no le hace caso y continúa con la ejecución

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude solucionar mi problema con lo siguiente:

cuando declaras los parámetros dentro del DataprocClusterCreateOperator
agregas un parámetro llamado **auto_delete_ttl** y le agregas el valor en segundos (rango que admite es de mínimo 10 minutos a un máximo de 14 días)

**auto_delete_ttl  = '3600'**

En este caso mi cluster contará con 1 hora para terminar el flujo completo, desde que se crea el cluster hasta que realice la serie de tareas posteriores, una vez que se cumpla el tiempo el cluster se eliminará automáticamente, y con esto evito que alguna tarea dilate mas tiempo y este consumiendo recursos innecesarios y tenga que detenerlo manualmente como era mi caso.

**Fuente:**
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/ClusterConfig